# TLS bootstraping nodes in k8s

Tags: kubernetes

As per the k8s official docs [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-tls-bootstrapping/)-

> The kubelet requires the following configuration to bootstrap:
>
> A path to store the key and certificate it generates (optional, can
>   use default)

What's the default path and where and how can I change the path where keys and certs generated for the kubelet  are stored?

Answer (score 2):

It is in `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount` by default.

You can run

```
kubectl exec POD_NAME -it -- ls /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
```

And you will get :

```
ca.crt  namespace  token
```

It is defined in spec.volumeMounts.mountPath

Example :

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    ...
    spec:
      containers:
     ...
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
          name: my-pod-token-ctmvg
          readOnly: true
  ...
      volumes:
      - name: my-pod-token-ctmvg
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          secretName: my-pod-token-ctmvg
```

In other words it's mounted to Pod's volume.

Comment: how to I modify this path if I have bootstrap-kubeconfig file?

Comment: Path is defined in Pod's manifest (or Deployment's Pod template).